# LilyPond: how to avoid spaces around \bold{}?

Tags: lilypond

It seems like `\bold` markup in LilyPond automatically adds surrounding spaces. Is there a way to avoid it?

Here is an example:

[image: example]

You can clearly see spaces between the brackets and the inside text.

Here is the code:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "italiano"

right = \relative do'' {
    \key sol \minor
    \tempo \markup {\normal-text {Andante con moto [\bold{Неторопливо}]}}
    <fa, sib re>2 <sol sib sol'>2 (
    <fa re' fa>4 <sol do mib>2.)
}

left = \relative do' {
    \key sol \minor
    <sib, sib'>2 <mib, mib'>2 (
    <sib sib'>4 <do do'>2.)
}

\score {
    \new PianoStaff <<
        \new Staff = "right" \right
        \new Staff = "left" { \clef bass \left }
    >>
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want the Russian text bolded?

Comment: I have an urtext of a piano piece by Musorgsky in a bad quality TIFF file. I am typesetting it to print a nice looking copy, and would like it to look exactly like the original. It plays better this way (part of my mental disability).

Comment: You could save the trouble: [Une Larme](https://imslp.org/wiki/Une_larme_(Mussorgsky%2C_Modest))  There's 4 scores there, you could see if one of them looks better than what you've got.  (I happen to own the book for the first one.)

Comment: Thanks! Do you play this one? We usually adjust fingers and make other small changes with my teacher, so I still would prefer my own engraved version. A pencil is of course fine for making changes, but my teacher is on the other side of the globe, it's nice when we have the same [edited] copy, so she can track me playing over Skype.

Comment: Besides, I am also having fun typesetting the music.

Comment: Yes, I've played it quite a bit - that's how I recognized it immediately from just the first 4 chords.  I'm not a pro by any means, but it is one of the easier pieces in that book.  I understand the appeal of typesetting it yourself, just figured I'd let you know that there are alternatives that would save you a bunch of work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the concatenation function `\concat{ }`:

`\concat{[\bold{Неторопливо}]}`

---

Another option would be to just put the bold function outside of the brackets:

`\bold{{[Неторопливо]}}`

but this would obviously make the brackets bold too.
(I assume this is not what you want)